# How to start a Tauri app running on Rust-Vite on desktop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rust, vite, tauri

I have a Tauri app with rust-vite and react. I can start my app on browser with the dev script, but how do I make it run on a separate canvas as a desktop app?

My package.json starts like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "tauri": "tauri"
  },
```

so usually I run `npm run dev` to kickoff, but that does not work in a browser in locahost.

I cannot get it start on a separate canvas as a desktop app, however that would be the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `npm run tauri dev` did the magic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).